# See the specific color names from one existing palette in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am looking to see the color name from `set1` palette. I need to use number 4 and 5 on my graph, that are the violet and orange one. I don't know their code. Please point me to where I could find their name or code. Thanks a lot.

The `set1` I am mentioning is here:

https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/ggplot2-qualitative-colour-palettes/

Thanks so much for any suggestion

Comment: They come from [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/), where you can look up values in hex or RGB or whatnot. "Set1" is the sixth (ironically) qualitative palette.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find out the code by `ggplot_build`.

```
# fake data
df <- data.frame(x=1:8, y=1, col=letters[1:8])

# Construct the plot
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=col)) + geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")

g
```

[image]

```
# Retrieve the color
colors <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]$colour

# Double check
plot(df$x, df$y, col=colors, pch=20, cex=5)
```

[image]

```
# color 4 and 5
colors[4:5]
[1] "#984EA3" "#FF7F00"
```

Comment: Also `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Set1")`